# Spring shell command line application returning null from a shell method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, command-line-interface, spring-shell

I have a simple CLI application that prints out your name from the official docs [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-shell/docs/2.1.1/site/reference/htmlsingle/).

```
@ShellComponent
public class Cli {

 @ShellMethod("Say my name")
 public String hi(@ShellOption(value = {"name"}) String arg1){
    return "Hi " + arg1 + "!!";
 }
}
```

When I run `hi --name Chandler` i get `Hi null!!` What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure that the version of spring-shell you are using matches the documentation you are using?

Use the above code, with Spring Boot 3.0.0 and Spring Shell 3.0.0-M3 works as expected.